# C#, Java SQLite Reading / Writing not possible

Tags: java, c#, database, sqlite

So I've got a java application which is running 24/7 writing into a database file. I'm using jdbc to write into the .db file.

I've got a C# Server which is supposed to read from that .db file and send information via networking to a client. Unfortunately this is only possible while the java application is not filling the .db with datas.

When the Java application is not activated the C# server is reading from that file and sending datas via networking flawlessly.

When the datacollector is activated and writing permantently to the database file my C# server cant read from it. In that case the client kills himself with a stackoverflow.

I'm using: jdbc for my java datacollector.

I'm using: System.Data.SQLite for my C# server.

I assumed that there will be only problems when 2 programs are writing to the .db file simultaneously, but since only my java application is writing to the file I thought this is going to work out.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A stack overflow means that your secret code is doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5
When your Java application is INSERTing into SQLite the database file is locked. So it cannot be accessed by another process. Exclusive lock is held until transaction is commited.

I don't think SQLite is suitable for this type of usage. I suggest you use real DBMS.

Comment: In case anyone finds this helpful, you can avoid this problem by setting the database journal mode to WAL. 
It supports concurrent readers and one writer.